# Why are these panels drawn misaligned when a canvas involved?

Tags: python, wxpython

[image]

Two (subclasses of) panels, a `CanvasSubPanel` (which draws a matplotlib figure) and `UnderPanel` are supposed to coexist in a vertical sizer.

While everything within the panels are rendered well, the panels themselves are drawn badly.

What is the solution?

---

Partial listing of `CanvasSubPanel` I believe is relevant:

```
class CanvasSubPanel(wx.Panel):
    #LENGTH, WIDTH = SIZE
    #_bitmap = None
    __click_callback = None

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.figure.set_size_inches( (10,5) )
        self.figure.set_dpi(80)
        #self.figure.tight_layout()

        self.picture   = self.figure.add_subplot(211)
        self.intensity = self.figure.add_subplot(212)
        ...       

        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure )
        ...

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()
```

Please respond if I missed important details.

Comment: I'm guessing they're not both in the same sizer with the right proportions or there is a parenting issue of some sort.

Comment: We both "solved" it at the same time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Mike Driscoll calls them, parenting issues.

The troubling panel was inadvertently set as child of a frame (like the other panel), not children of a panel with a sizer.